# Save java object tree with versioning?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a Java application which saves a object tree to file using default java object serialization (`ObjectOutputStream` and such). This works quite nicely.

The problem arises when I add a field to an object that is in the object tree. When I now load the old object tree I get a `ClassException`, which of course makes sense cause that object/class changed and the old class doesn't match the new class.

Now I can write different versions of my load method so that it can handle old object trees, but I suspect this might become not very easy to manage and maintain.

I was wondering if there is a better way to save a object tree in java which supports versioning?

Comment: You can use the `readObject` and `writeObject` methods in your Serializable class in order to define the default behavior when serializing/deserializing the object from your file.

Comment: I wouldn't use Java serialization for long-term storage. I would use a database, or XML, or JSON, or any other parseable and easily migratable format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this approach (implementing `readObject` and `writeObject`) to handle schema migration: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2006/jw-0227-control.html

Comment: I just have to stop writing comments and turn them into answers =\

Comment: Cheers Ranjan and Luiggi! And thanks for the article link, was an interesting read.

Answer (score 0):

use the    readObject()
and    writeObject()
methods of ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream class in your Serializable class 
in order to define the default behavior when serializing/deserializing the object from 
your file 
    ObjectOutputStream    oos    =    new    ObjectOutputStream(file/path/url);
    oos.writeObject(serialized Object);
    oos.close();
    oos.flush();
    ObjectInputStream ois =   new    ObjectInputStream(file/path/url/request);
    Object    obj    =    (TypeCast to appropriate Object)ois.readObject();